# LINQ expression instead of nested foreach loops

Tags: c#, linq

I have these  two clases:

```
public class Client{
    public List<Address> addressList{get;set;}
} 

public class Address{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a List of type `Client` called `testList`. It contains n clients and each one of those contains n addresses

```
List<Client> testList;
```

how can i do the following using LINQ:

```
foreach (var element in testList)
{
    foreach (var add in element.addressList)
    {
        console.writeLine(add.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for a LINQ query. They utilize lambda expressions to reach their goal, but it's not the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I wouldn't put the `Console.WriteLine` in a lambda expression, but you can use `SelectMany` to avoid the nesting:

```
foreach (var add in testList.SelectMany(x => x.addressList))
{
    Console.WriteLine(add.name);
}
```

I see little reason to convert the results to a list and then use `List<T>.ForEach` when there's a perfectly good `foreach` loop as part of the language. It's not like you naturally *have* a delegate to apply to each name, e.g. as a method parameter - you're always just writing to the console. See [Eric Lippert's blog post on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) for more thoughts.

(I'd also strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Side note:  Just received your new (updated) book.  I've only read a couple chapters but I like it a LOT!

Comment: Thanks, I really should have spent more time writing up the example, but i will read up on the naming conventions @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(var a in testList.SelectMany(c => c.addressList))
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.name);
}
```

It will not materialize any new collection.

Answer (score 2):

This may helps:

```
testList.ForEach(i => i.addressList.ForEach(j => Console.WriteLine(j.name)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(var add in testList.SelectMany(element => element.addressList)){
    Console.WriteLine(add.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
testList.SelectMany(c => c.addressList)
        .Select(a => a.name)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(Console.WriteLine)
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of materializing new `List<string>` just to use `List<T>.ForEach` method to print all the items.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek agree, it would be nice to have `ForEach` extension on `IEnumerable`. I just wanted to do all in one line with lambdas, as OP asks

Comment: I don't like the idea of `void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)` either.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I don't like premature optimizations

Answer (score 1):

Use the ForEach method:

```
testList.ForEach(tl=>tl.addressList.ForEach(al=>console.writeLine(al.name)));
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ doesn't include a `ForEach` function, [and they don't intend to](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mazhou/archive/2011/09/21/why-no-foreach-method-on-ienumerable-interfaces.aspx), since it goes against the idea of LINQ being [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) methods. So you can't do this in a single statement. `List<T>` has a [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, but I'd recommend not using this for the same reasons that it's not in LINQ.

You can, however, use LINQ to simplify your code, e.g.

```
foreach (var add in testList.SelectMany(x => x.addressList))
{
    Console.WriteLine(add.name);
}
// or
foreach (var name in testList.SelectMany(x => x.addressList).Select(x => x.name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```